# DB2 python insert list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sql, db2, prepared-statement

I have a list of dictionaries that I'd like to insert into a DB2 table. How can I do that? I'm using the `ibm_db` DB2 driver. Here's my code:

```
list_of_dictionaries = []
sql = "INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (...)"
ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
```

The problem is that the table as well as the dictionaries have more than a hundred columns/keys, so I prefer not to list all column names in my SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can insert a list of dictionaries into a DB2 table using `ibm_db` driver:

```
for i in list_of_dictionaries:

    columns = ', '.join(i.keys())
    placeholders = ', '.join(['?'] * len(i))

    insert_sql = "INSERT INTO schema.table ( " + columns + ") VALUES ( " + placeholders + ")"
    stmt_insert = ibm_db.prepare(conn, insert_sql)

    try:
        ibm_db.execute(stmt_insert, tuple(i.values()))
    except:
        print "Transaction couldn't be completed:" , ibm_db.stmt_errormsg()
    else:
        print "sucessfully inserted "
```

**P.S:** As you're doing a bulk insert, you could use the function `ibm_db.execute_many()`, however it will give you less flexibility for error handling, etc.